# Event target as a returned value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Does anyone know how can I access an event target?
i.e, say I have a function:

```
func(event){...}
```

so that parameter "event" is a string which describes the event name (such as "onclick"/"onload" etc.), how can I get the target of this?
Suppose the given parameter is "onclick" and the click that happened was on a button called "button1", how can I get button1 as a returned value?

Thanks!

Comment: What, why would the event object be a string? This makes no sense, post some code and try to explain this a little better.

Comment: Can't you use $(this)?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you edited the function context (as with `$.proxy`), then you can use `this` to get the current element (and `$(this)` will return the jquery object).

Regardless if you did edit the context, you can always use `event.currentTarget` (or `$(event.currentTarget)` for the jQuery object, again)